# IOS app crash - but not in simulator - hardcoding URL works

Tags: ios, json, swift

after a successful build through xcode, the app runs in the simulator and my iPhone - when I distribute it for testing, it crashes when test users try to preform a search.

If i hardcode the URL elements - it works in both simulation mode and functions perfectly in the users test trials.

i have CrashLytics operating and it says the crash is a result of this line of code

```
let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: urlResults!)
```

i check in the previous VC that all the fields contain a value - and a "print" confirms the same

```
Company : Accountant
Suburb  : Southport
State   : QLD
Getting results from: http://www.myawsmurl.com.au/api/get_details.php?no=Accountant&state=QLD&suburb=Southport
```

var's are set at the top of the class via the following:

```
var toSearchFor: String = ""
var toSearchForSuburb: String = ""
var toSearchForState: String = ""
```

and this is the func that causes the issue:

```
func getResults() {
    toSearchFor = searchingFor.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    toSearchForSuburb = searchingSuburb.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    toSearchForState = searchingState.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    print("Company : \(toSearchFor)")
    print("Suburb  : \(toSearchForSuburb)")
    print("State   : \(toSearchForState)")

    //toSearchFor = "Accountant"
    //toSearchForSuburb = "Southport"
    //toSearchForState = "QLD"

    //print("Company : \(toSearchFor)")
    //print("Suburb  : \(toSearchForSuburb)")
    //print("State   : \(toSearchForState)")

    let searchURL = ("http://www.myawsmurl.com.au/api/get_details.php?no=" + toSearchFor + "&state=" + toSearchForState + "&suburb=" + toSearchForSuburb)
    let urlResults = URL(string:searchURL)
    print("Getting results from: \(searchURL)")

    do {
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: urlResults!)
        let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : NSArray]

        etc etc
    }
    catch {

    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

as mentioned before, if i uncomment the hardcoded vars, it runs as excepted without issues.

any help would be appreciated as i still cant figure out why it runs in simulation mode without any issues but fails on live testing even though all fields have a value.

**EDIT: (crash data)**

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ThisAWSMAPP                    0x1000752e4 ViewController.getResults() -> () (ViewController.swift:158)
1  ThisAWSMAPP                    0x100076180 specialized ViewController.viewDidAppear(Bool) -> () (ViewController.swift)
2  ThisAWSMAPP                    0x100071e3c @objc ViewController.viewDidAppear(Bool) -> () (ViewController.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x18cb0ddb0 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 856
4  UIKit                          0x18cb0e31c -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 228
5  UIKit                          0x18cbc4d64 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1224
6  UIKit                          0x18cc93c5c __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 232
7  UIKit                          0x18cc1aa1c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 116
8  UIKit                          0x18cd68fac __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke.99 + 724
9  UIKit                          0x18cb2e9d0 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 492
10 UIKit                          0x18cb2e4f8 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
11 UIKit                          0x18cb2e314 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 160
12 QuartzCore                     0x189cdf0d4 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 260
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18587e9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1858835e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 996
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1869750c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
16 CoreFoundation                 0x186972cdc __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1868a2d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
18 GraphicsServices               0x18830c074 GSEventRunModal + 100
19 UIKit                          0x18cb5b130 UIApplicationMain + 208
20 ThisAWSMAPP                    0x1000646d8 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x1858b159c start + 4
```

Comment: You should add the crash log or exact crash message.

Comment: Maybe some value is nil, test again with them

Comment: The carsh at that line indicates your urlResults is getting nil somehow.

Comment: the "searchURL" is the same whether i hardcode the values or get them dynamically - its just one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: seems like value is getting nil when its accessed . or please share crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. URL(string:) may return nil if the string is not a correctly formatted URL. It is not safe to force unwrap it as `urlResults!`, especially if you are constructing it from user input.

It safer like this:

```
if let url = urlResults {
    let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf:url) 
    // etc
} else {
    // log an error for debugging
}
```

2. You should make sure the strings are URL encoded

String.trimmingCharacters only removes characters from beginning and end of the string. But your input variables may contain embedded spaces, or other illegal characters for a URL string.

Translate the input strings like this:

```
toSearchFor = searchingFor.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: @Dale - could you explain why the console outputs the same information whether i hardcode the values or get them dynamically. i can understand why your code is needed - but i tested the original code with my own input for the vales of "Accountant", "Southport" and "QLD" - and why would it work in simulation mode but not externally ?

Comment: What we don't see in your code is where searchingFor etc are coming from. The content of these, which seem to be user input, are likely the cause. Even though they may appear ok when printed, depending on the encoding they may actually be different. Try printing out the strings after addingPercentEncoding

Comment: that seemed to work perfectly - although it still printed the same results - not sure why the simulator doesn't simulate so to speak :s

Answer (score 0):

The carsh at the given line indicates your `urlResults` is getting nil somehow.

Try encoding the url string before making URL object.

```
let toSearchFor = ""
let toSearchForSuburb = ""
let toSearchForState = ""

let searchURL = ("http://www.myawsmurl.com.au/api/get_details.php?no=" + toSearchFor + "&state=" + toSearchForState + "&suburb=" + toSearchForSuburb).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: . urlQueryAllowed)

if let url = searchURL, let urlResults = URL(string:url) {
    print("Getting results from: \(url)")

    do {
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: urlResults!)
        let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : NSArray]
    }
    catch {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like thread issue. Can you try executing your code on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async({
let searchURL = ("http://www.myawsmurl.com.au/api/get_details.php?no=" + toSearchFor + "&state=" + toSearchForState + "&suburb=" + toSearchForSuburb)
    let urlResults = URL(string:searchURL)
    print("Getting results from: \(searchURL)")

    do {
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: urlResults!)
        let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : NSArray]

        etc etc
    }
    catch {}
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```